# Updating existing Archive File

Tags: shell

I have to add 1 file under one sub archive file in the existing archive file.

File1

> META-INF
>   arhiveFile ( this is also archive file)
>   META-INF

currently I tried using shell script
- Created folder META-INF
- Using zip command but its adding under file1 --> META-INF
  I already tried searching in google but could find if i can give the location where this needs to be 
  added. 
  Please suggest.

Comment: what i did now..i create Folder META-INF/File and zipped it with the "Abcd XYZ.appzip" as zip type as the archiveFile  and then i executed the command "zip -gr abcd.bar "Abcd XYZ.appzip"  but i am getting below error: zip warning: Local Entry CRC does not match CD: Abcd XYZ.appzip

Comment: I get the zip warning `Local Entry CRC does not match CD` too when I do `zip -r file.zip dir/`.